# AttributeError: type object 'FieldFile' has no attribute 'field'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

This is the validation I'm using in `views.py`

```
if form.is_valid():
    FieldFile.save(self=FieldFile, name=file, content=file, save=True)
    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

Here's `forms.py`

```
class UploadFile(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

And `models.py`

```
grid_fs_storage = GridFSStorage(collection='images', base_url=''.join([settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images/']))
grid_fs_storage_video = GridFSStorage(collection='videos', base_url=''.join([settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'videos/']))

# Create your models here.
class Uploads(models.Model):
    uploaded_file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images', storage=grid_fs_storage)
    uploaded_video = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='videos', storage=grid_fs_storage)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `FieldFile.save` you are calling a method on the class, but you should use an instance e.g. `form.file.save(name, content)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile _"When you access a `FileField` on a model, you are given an instance of `FieldFile` as a proxy for accessing the underlying file."_

Comment: Using this `form.file.save(name=file, content=file)` Error I am getting is `AttributeError: 'UploadFile' object has no attribute 'file'` 
Everything else is the same

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Also, try to read the error message to see where he error comes from. Sounds like either `form` or `file` var is the wrong type of object for how you're trying to use it

Comment: The error is coming from the same line itself. `form.file.save(name=file, content=file)`. And which code would you like to see more of? And BDW I'm trying to upload images to MongoDB database, I had a code which uploads but is somehow not saving the images to local. Could this be related to anything?